# Operand error when using an integer in a list

Tags: python, list, integer, operands

I've been trying to work on this code for hours but keep getting to the same point every time. Basically I'm trying to add up all the values in an array.  However, it keeps saying unsupported operand for integer and list.  I'm confused why it is saying that because the list consists of integers.  This is in python.

```
hours = [0,0,0,0,0]

i=0 
while i < 5:
    print (days[i])
    hours [i] = int(input('How many hours did you work for the day above? \n'))
    i+=1
    print('\n')
    
for x in range(len(days)):
    print('\n')
    print (days [x])
    print (hours[x])

total = 0
for x in hours:
    total += hours
```

Above is the fraction of the code that I believe is the problem

```
    total += hours
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

Above is the error I keep getting

Comment: You want to add `x` in that statement. `hours` is the list you're iterating over, `x` is the individual item. Instead of writing the loop, though, you could just do `total = sum(hours)`

Comment: @U In other words, instead of `total += hours`, it should be `total += x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall) and [@Ben Grossmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2476977/ben-grossmann) have correctly pointed out, you're trying to add a number to a list:

```
total += hours
```

- `total` is an integer number (`total = 0`)
- `hours` is a list (`hours = [0,0,0,0,0]`)

Change your code to this to make it work:

```
for x in hours:
    total += x
```

**Side note:**

There is an elegant way to get the sum of a list of numbers:

```
total = sum(hours)
```

`sum()` is a built-in function (it comes with Python out-of-the-box). You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).